# How to publish Python 3 source-less RPMs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pyc

We're having a Python 2 product we publish as RPMs. The RPMs include only the pyo/pyc files, and the running scripts refer to certain pyo files to run the product. We use setuptools to package these RPM:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --release=... --requires=... --bdist-base=...
```

We're now porting out product to Python 3.6, and found that pyc files [no longer reside in the same location](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) as the py files. They are located in a __pycache__ folder under the folder of the py files, and moreover, they will not work if the corresponding py file does not exist. There is still support in legacy behavior if the pyc file is replacing the py file, and is not in __pycache__.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/compileall.html) shows that the python compileall can accept a -b flag that:

> Write the byte-code files to their legacy locations and names, which
>   may overwrite byte-code files created by another version of Python.
>   The default is to write files to their PEP 3147 locations and names,
>   which allows byte-code files from multiple versions of Python to
>   coexist.

However, since we use setuptools, we do not control the compilation command line.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to tell setuptools to compile the code with the -b flag and keep the legacy location of pyc files?
2. Is there a better way in Python 3 to publish source-less RPMs and still be able to call the pyc file from a script?

Comment: Can you provide simple example if it's a closed source program ? Some proof of concept and how do you compile it with `setuptools` ?